# Windows 7 Wireless Networking: Wireless Network Profiles keep coming back and Automatically Connecting?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

In Windows 7, I connected to a WPA2-Enterprise network which required authentication. That network had numerous issues, but after awhile I was able to get access to a hard cable connection. Since this network requires authentication every time it connects, it is now popping up every 30 seconds or so saying "Additional information is needed to connect to [the network SSID]."

So naturally I went into "Manage Wireless Networks" and removed the network. But after 30 seconds or so, the network re-appears in the list, saying "Automatically Connect"! I tried just un-checking "Connect automatically when this network is in range", and then it says "Manually Connect" -- but after 30 seconds, the network reverts to "Automatically Connect" and continues asking me for my credentials!

*What the heck??*

(I'm using Windows 7 Professional 64-bit with the Centrino-N E6205 adapter).

Comment: Sounds like you have 3rd party wireless management software installed.

Comment: really what the heck, did you try disable instead?

|Network and Sharing Center| Change Adapter settings| select adapter, right click , select disable.

Comment: @Moab: That WAS the answer, fantasic. Can you please add an actual Answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: @Psycogeek: Thanks for the suggestion, but I didn't want to disable the adapter, I still want to be able to connect to a wireless network whenever. I just wanted this particular network to stop connecting automatically every 30 seconds.

Comment: More information: My Intel Centrino-N was being managed by Intel's ProSet wireless management software, and Windows was also trying to manage it -- the resulting conflict meant that Intel kept overriding/switching back my settings and trying to connect. Right-clicking the Intel ProSet icon in systray gave me the option to let Windows manage the connection. Alternatively, I could have turned off Windows management for the adapter and used the Intel software instead.

Comment: @Brian Lacy answer posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check to see if you have 3rd party wireless management software installed, if so check the configuration or uninstall it and let Windows manage the wireless connections.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling Intel Wi-Fi management software and setting Wi-Fi to be managed by Windows have fixed it for me.